Visual Studio and C projects?
I have a simple C file that compile fine in the developer command prompt using a basic cl command.
cl C:\some_path\src\test2.c /Zi
But when I set this up as a Visual Studio project and run it (x64/Debug), I get bunch of errors and warning.
What kind of basics I need to have setup so I can run the project from within Visual Studio.
The following also works:
devenv test2.exe will load the source code, run it and debug it just fine.
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current
Version 17.9.5
Error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Error   C4996   'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.   test    C:\some_path\nob.h  392

Warnings:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Warning C6308   'realloc' might return null pointer: assigning null pointer to '((render))->items', which is passed as an argument to 'realloc', will cause the original memory block to be leaked. test    C:\some_path\nob.h  472

Here is test.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <crtdbg.h>

#define NOB_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "nob.h"

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

int main(void)
{
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    int c = 0;

    nob_log(NOB_INFO, "[002] Hello World!");

    int* foo = malloc(56);

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    return 0;
}


What errors and warnings do you have gotten?

I mean, if it builds in cmd shouldn't it build from within Visual Studio?

Both errors are actually warnings. You have a setting to treat warnings as errors somewhere. Better yet, follow the suggestions and make fixes to the code.

Treat Warnings as Errors is No (/WX-)

As @EugeneSh. says, these are warnings that are treated as errors. This is the default setting when using Visual Studio, as it helps you to find not only actual errors, but potential ones which may not be obvious at first. The compiler is actually helping you to address these with suggestions as to making your code more robust.

I disabled the external header, and it is building now. But as I said, it builds with that header in cmd using cl, but not building from within Visual Studio. -- Because of that this seems like a dead end. The header file is this: https://github.com/tsoding/musializer/blob/master/src/nob.h
I don't see how the code will compile with this header file in cmd but no from within Visual Studio.

To avoid the first warning include the following macro before include directives
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

As for the second warning then you need to use an intermediate pointer to store the result of a call of realloc and test it before assigning its value to the original pointer. Otherwise you can overwrite the original pointer wil returned null value and as result you will get a memory leak.
For example
int *p = malloc( sizeof( int ) );

//...

int *tmp = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( int ) );

if ( tmp != NULL )
{
    p = tmp;
    //...
}
else
{
    // some other code
}

//...

free( p );

If you will just write
p = realloc( p, 2 * sizeof( int ) );

then in case of a failure of the memory reallocation the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost because the pointer p in this case becomes equal to NULL.

@Dúthomhas I have appended my answer with such a code snippet.

The problem is that Visual Studio doesn't like the header in there, but cl is ok to build the exe in cmd, with the very same header.

@mbilyanov It seems it depends on default settings of compiler options.

#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS had to be at the very top, obviously. Now it runs at least. Thank you!

@mbilyanov No at all. You are welcome.:)

I vaguely remember that in the past it was required for some reason to put _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in the project settings (preprocessor definitions). But I tried now to put it before all the #include directives as you suggested, and it worked like a charm.
